# Setting up a Gmail canned response for the beginning of a conversation

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-canned-response

I've followed some guides (like [this one](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-send-canned-replies-automatically-in-gmail-1172080)) to set up an autoresponse service in Gmail.

I want **just one** automatic email **for each conversation start**. Using filters+templates, like it's described in the guide above, and filtering by `label:inbox` or `label:unread` does the trick but it triggers other automatic sendings later, if the conversation goes on with other messages.

How can I avoid that?

<sub>Default Out of office service is not an option, since it does not send new responses in a rolling window of four days.</sub>